# How to combine several entities into one in entity framework (map complex entity into single table)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Just for example. I have two models

```
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set: }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Birth Date { get; set; }
}
public class Birth {
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

How to make the entity framework seeing the 'Person' entity like this:

```
public class Person {
    public int Id { get; set: }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

i.e. EF should map it into single table.

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit more. By "seeing" do you mean that EF should map it into single table or something else?

Comment: You can have a custom class in your models folder with a any name "CombinedPersonBirth" then inside that class make a property with type Person and second property with data type Birth. then use this class in your view and controller.

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, I meant it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using EF Core this can be achieved with so called ["Owned Entities"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities). Using atrributes:

```cs
public class Person 
{
    public int Id { get; set: }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Birth Date { get; set; }
}

[Owned]
public class Birth 
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

Or explicit configuration:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().OwnsOne(p => p.Date);
```

Note that `Birth` fields will be prefixed.

Comment: @Whishare you can read here more about owned entities https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects